# Installed ubuntu and now Ethernet doesn't work

Tags: networking, 17.04

I bought a new computer that was running Linux mint and the network was fine. I did a fresh install of ubuntu 17.04 over it and now my Ethernet connection isn't working. I made sure the cables weren't loose and tried a few terminal commands that I saw in other posts, but it'll just say these things aren't installed. When I try to install them it says it can't. Probably because I have no connection? Help a noob out?

Comment: Did you download updates while installing Ubuntu? And might need a usb or dvd to re-install.

Comment: Are you able to get a wireless connection? What make/model computer? Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Ping me `@heynnema` when you have the info.